# How can i attach a color block to my li list?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, append, html-lists

I have a list that in JavaScript shows an appended array, the problem is that I can't figure out how to take my color block from the first test one and append to all the `<li>`.

How can I go about fixing this?

Here is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
SELECT A COLOR

    <div class="dropdown-container">
      <ul class="swatches" id="swatches">
        <li class="cell">
          COLOR 1
          <div class="colorBox"></div>
          <!--END COLOR BOX-->
        </li>
        <!--END LI-->
      </ul>
      <!--END SWATCHES-->
    </div>
    <!--END DROPDOWN CONTAINER-->
```

JS:

```
//Establish the text array
  var colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "purple", "orange", "teal", "yellow"];

  //loop for text name
  for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    //set color for each
    var name = colors[i];
    //grab the ul- swatches
    var ul = document.getElementById("swatches");
    //creates the new li
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    //appending the array to the li
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'colorBox';
    li.appendChild(div);
    //appending the li to the ul 
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
```

CSS:

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: roboto;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.dropdown-container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

ul.swatches {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  color: #333333;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul.swatches li {
  width: 80%;
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

ul.swatches li:hover {
  background-color: pink;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul.swatches li .colorBox {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -25px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Then I have my jsfiddle file that has everything working but a color block.
Any ideas?

https://jsfiddle.net/kotten03/xwt708Lb/228/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following snipet. It basically adds the `div` with class `colorBox` to each list item.

```
  //Establish the text array
  var colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "purple", "orange", "teal", "yellow"];


  //loop for text name
  for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    //set color for each
    var name = colors[i];
    //grab the ul- swatches
    var ul = document.getElementById("swatches");

    //creates the new li
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    //appending the array to the li
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'colorBox'
    li.appendChild(div);

    //appending the li to the ul 
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
```

Comment: perfect! I tried a lot, but did not try class name! thank you! I have another question... how can i use actual hex colors to change that solid blue to match the name?

Comment: Cheers man, https://jsfiddle.net/vphwzds3/. Just use .style.backgroundColor = ..., as shown in the fiddle.